# $\xi$ is continuous but not necessarily analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

If $\xi:\mathbb{C}-\{0\}\to \Bbb{C}$ is a function such that $\xi(z)=\xi(\frac{z}{|z|})$ and its restriction to the unit circle is continuous, then $\xi$ is continuous but not necessarily analytic.

I didn't find anything to start this problem. Can I find some hints?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $\xi$ is the composition of two continous functions
- An analytic function that is constant on the positive real line must be constant.

Comment: The $f(z)= \frac{z}{{\left| z \right|}}$ is a continuous map from $\mathbb{C}\setminus 
\left\{ 0 \right\}$ to the unit circle. By assumption $\xi$ is continuous on the unit circle, whence $\xi(z)=\xi (f(z))$ is a continuous map (because it is the composition of two continuous functions).